# Adapting Blogger's Featured Post Gadget to show recent posts of specific labels

Tags: javascript, html, css, blogger

Essentially the title says it all. Would you anybody know how to adapt Blogger's Featured Post Gadget so that instead of showing recent posts from my entire site, it could just show recent posts from a certain label? I just want a widget that can show the most recent post (just 1 post) from one of my labels.

This is the link to my site. The gadget I'm talking about is called Random Post on the site:http://newsotuniverse.blogspot.ca/

I'll also provide some code from site for you non-Blogger users to see if you can tackle the problem:

```
          <b:widget id='FeaturedPost1' locked='false' title='Random Post' type='FeaturedPost'>
            <b:widget-settings>
              <b:widget-setting name='showSnippet'>true</b:widget-setting>
              <b:widget-setting name='showPostTitle'>true</b:widget-setting>
              <b:widget-setting name='showFirstImage'>true</b:widget-setting>
              <b:widget-setting name='useMostRecentPost'>true</b:widget-setting>
            </b:widget-settings>
            <b:includable id='main'>
  <!-- Only display title if it's non-empty -->
  <b:if cond='data:title != &quot;&quot;'>
    <h2 class='title'><data:title/></h2>
  </b:if>
  <b:include name='content'/>

  <b:include name='quickedit'/>
</b:includable>
            <b:includable id='content'>
  <div class='post-summary'>
    <b:if cond='data:showPostTitle and data:postTitle != &quot;&quot;'>
      <h3><a expr:href='data:postUrl'><data:postTitle/></a></h3>
    </b:if>
    <b:if cond='data:showSnippet and data:postSummary != &quot;&quot;'>
      <p>
        <data:postSummary/>
      </p>
    </b:if>
    <b:if cond='data:showFirstImage and data:postFirstImage != &quot;&quot;'>
      <img class='image' expr:src='data:postFirstImage'/>
    </b:if>
  </div>

  <style type='text/css'>
    .image {
      width: 100%;
    }
  </style>
</b:includable>
          </b:widget>
```

Would really appreciate it if someone could help. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is my answer helpful, or do you need some more help?

Comment: now my answer should solve your problem more clearly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:** I updated the code it filters now the posts for the label `label1`.

I don't ***think*** it is possible, since you can't access the **labels** property from the featured Post data element, **but** you could replace the FeaturedPost Widget with a Blog Widget, with Code like this:

```html
<b:widget id='Blog2' locked='true' title='FeaturedBlog' type='Blog' >
  <b:includable id='main'>
    <div class='post-summary'>
      <b:with var="filteredData" value="data:posts filter (p =&gt; p.labels any ( l =&gt; l.name == &quot;label0&quot; ))">     
        <b:loop values='data:filteredData' var='post' index='index'>
          <b:if cond='data:index == "0"' > 
            <h3><a expr:href='data:post.url'><data:post.title/></a></h3>
            ...
          </b:if>  
        </b:loop>
      </b:with>
   </div>
  <b:include name='quickedit'/>
  </b:includable>
</b:widget>
```

- It is not so sexy, and you would have to copy the html-structure from the Featured Post Widget
- you would have to change `id='Blog2'` according to your needs.

> **Mini Explanation to the filtering:**
>   *`data:posts filter (p =&gt; p.labels any ( l =&gt; l.name == &quot;label0&quot; ))`*
>   **data:posts**: get all Posts
>   **filter**: is a lambda function, that will be called for all posts( to filter items ) and returns only "fitting" items
>   **(p => ... )**: is the outer function "construct" 
>   **p.labels**: `p` is the current post, `labels` are the labels of the current post
>   **any**: is an other lambda function, that returns `true` if one items  "fits"
>   **(l => l.name == "label0")** ... inner function checking if the post has a label with the name `label0`

Here a link to a good inofficial reference website: http://template-data.blogspot.co.at

Comment: What would I change id='Blog2' to?

Comment: @K. Tam If you have no blog-widget (`type="Blog"`) in the template set it to `Blog1`, if you have one or more look for the highest number and add one to the name. (example.: highest is `Blog1` set it to `Blog2`, and so on). I hope this helps.

Comment: @K.Tam did my answer help? If so can you please accept it. Thanks